# Last column in grid needs custom title

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-grid, extjs5

So I am using ExtJS to render grids with data. I have features on the grid which are good but I want to last row to say "Total of All" but it's repeating the first group title.

Below is my custom group header:

```
features: [{
        ftype: 'summary'
    }, {
        //ftype: 'grouping'
        ftype: 'groupingsummary',
        groupHeaderTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '',
            '{name:this.formatName} ({rows.length})',
            {
                formatName: function(name) {
                    return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
                }
            }
        ),
        //groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ({rows.length})',
        hideGroupedHeader: true
    }],
```

And here is the summery type config that is producing the totals title:

```
columns: [{
                id       :'service-product',
                text   : 'Product',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'PACKAGE',
                summaryType: function(records) {
                    var myGroupName = records[0].get('LISTING');
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'+myGroupName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myGroupName.slice(1)+' Totals</span>';
                }
            }
```

Here is the screenshot with the highlighted title i want to make custom. I have tried a few things. Anyone know how to get a reference to this cell and change the the title?

[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Nathan

Comment: Is `myGroupName` "Renting Totals"?

Comment: `var myGroupName = records[0].get('LISTING');` So what ever it is at that time first "renting" then "sales" but then it's down as "renting" again. I want the very last row to be custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at `this` inside `summaryType`. I have noticed that when it is invoked for total group it points to `Ext.data.Store`, and when it is called for 'normal' group it points to `Ext.util.Group`.

So example `summaryType` may look like this:

```
summaryType: function(records) {
    console.log(this.$className);
    if (this.isStore) {
        return "Total of all";
    }
    var myGroupName = records[0].get('group');
    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">' + myGroupName + ' Totals</span>';
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/b2LS5/4/